# Bootstrap modal with opacity appearing behind the background

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal that is included inside a faded div.

For some reason, the modal, after opening, is behind the grey background and is thus not accessible.

## Code

#### HTML

```
<div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#normal" data-toggle=
    "modal">Normal</button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="normal" role="dialog"
    tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="faded">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#faded-modal" data-toggle=
    "modal">Faded</button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="faded-modal" role=
    "dialog" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#faded {
   opacity: 0.7;
}
```

## Results

#### Normal

[image: Normal]

#### Faded

[image: Faded]

[Demo here](http://jsbin.com/jicowuraqo/1/edit?html,css,output)

As you can see on the example the first modal is correctly displayed and the second one (the faded one) is appearing behind the background, inaccessible.

How can I change this behavior? The modal should be displayed as usual ...

**Notes:** I cannot change the HTML, and I need to keep the opacity on the parent, this is a simpler example to show the effect but there are other elements that are faded as well.

Comment: For the persons who downvoted me, can I at least have a comment?

Comment: I didn't (and won't) but you aren't showing the required minimal markup that represents the problem. And a link to a third party site isn't good enough. That link can disappear tomorrow and be of no value to anyone now or later. This will only get your question closed. Post your minimum markup here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second modal is also appearing in front of the background, but it is faded to 0.7 opacity because the parent element is.  If you want to achieve it unfaded, you'll need to make the parent div transparent and stick a new one in with 100% width and height, the background colour and opacity set.  You'll also need to use z-orders to make sure it appears behind the modal.

Comment: Make sens, do you think it's possible to achieve this without changing the parent's background?

Comment: As far as I know, opacity applied to all child elements, so the only way around it is to apply it to something that isn't a parent of the modal.  The visible effect should be that you have a background with an opacity and a solid modal though

Answer (score 0):

Don't apply the "faded" id to the div around the button. Apply it to the button itself. To have a faded button, apply the faded as a class to the button.

```
.faded{
  opacity: 0.7;
}

<div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary faded" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#faded-modal">Faded</button>...
```

http://jsbin.com/jefimarewi

Comment: I updated my question, I need to keep the parent faded and the button inside the parent.

Comment: what on earth is the parent? You have to be specific here.

Comment: The surrounding `div`, the direct parent of the modal and the button. This one has to be faded, in the example provided, it's a `div#faded`.

Comment: I don't get what you're asking. My fiddle shows it how you want it in your screenshot provided only the actual modal is not faded. The background and surrounding div all look faded. You obviously can't add the faded style to that div since it caused the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111780/discussion-between-nobe4-and-rachel-s).

Answer (score 0):

Working Code, Just Added faded css to button only

```css
#faded{
  opacity: 0.7;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

<div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#normal">Normal</button>

<div id="normal" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum sequi, quod, id aut tempora soluta commodi deleniti ratione nesciunt, tenetur iste incidunt veniam dolores accusantium corporis, laboriosam nam provident est.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
  
<div id="faded">   <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#faded-modal">Faded</button></div>
  
  
 

<div id="faded-modal" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum sequi, quod, id aut tempora soluta commodi deleniti ratione nesciunt, tenetur iste incidunt veniam dolores accusantium corporis, laboriosam nam provident est.</p>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated my question, I need to keep the parent faded and not just the button.

Comment: use jquery on modal open like $(#faded-modal").on("show.bs.modal", function(){ $(#faded-modal").removeClass("faded");});   Rest you can put your modal inside div with class faded(i e same as your existing markup) other wise you can put everything inside the div.faded but not the modal.

Answer (score 0):

The  `<div class="modal fade"...` has to be moved out of the `<div id="faded">...` so that it does not take the  `<div class="modal fade"...`  as its parent div..

I.e. instead of

```
<div id="faded">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#faded-modal" data-toggle=
    "modal">Faded</button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="faded-modal" role=
    "dialog" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

TRY...

```
<div id="faded">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#faded-modal" data-toggle=
    "modal">Faded</button>

</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="faded-modal" role=
    "dialog" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```